# Wallet system like odesk

Tags: php, yii

Hello guys I am currently developing an auction website with the yii framework and I am planning on implementing a wallet system for my users like in odesk..however I am not so sure about the security.. my questions is:

- What are the risks for this wallet system?
- Are there any extensions out there for this system?

Thanks..Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: All I know is that ar doesn't support many doctrine like ar queries. But it's really fast and easy to learn. Also a good small community

Comment: Hello Sir thank you for your reply however I am not asking about the yii framework..

Comment: If you're asking about it - you definitely will have issues with security.

Comment: Oh. As you have heard recently about the bitcoin wallet system. It was hacked numerous times. You will have an issue with security regardless

Comment: Yes I have heard about the bitcoin issue..However I am wondering What did the odesk.com used for their wallet system?

Comment: @NEWBIE: odesk didn't use any ready to use components for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main risk that such a system will expose you to has nothing to do with programming, but is worth mentioning anyway: operating such a system will cause your web site to be classified by many governments as a [money transmitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_transmitter), which will impose a number of complex legal requirements on you. It will also make it very difficult for you to move money in and out of the system, as most of the normal providers (e.g, credit card processors and PayPal) do not permit the operation of money transmitters.

Consult a lawyer for details. This stuff is very complicated, and the details will depend on what countries you intend to do business in.

Comment: thnx for the information.. I was planning to do this to hold payments like for example.. A Seller didn't deliver the item to the buyer I need to hold the payment and then once the buyer confirmed that the item has been delivered The payment will be transferred to the account of the seller..is there any possible way to attain the same logic?

Comment: Again: talk to a lawyer. What you are describing is an escrow service; operating such a service is quite complex. It is not going to be easy to run - you will be expected to mediate and investigate disputes.